# how to design auto fit for all iPhone devices like 4,5,6 and 6+ using storyboard auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, autolayout

I need help to design the layout for 3 rows and 2 columns of uibuttons in a single view controller on storyboard. Its fit for all iPhone devices like 4s, 5,6,and 6 plus. I don't know how to use the constraints. Please guide me to do this. Here is the sample image i want like this [image: I want to design like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a sample project for this. You may take some idea from it;

http://jmp.sh/Xli1hQ1

Comment: Thanks a lot its perfect but I need buttons on the layout, How can i change the views to buttons

Comment: replace view with UIButtons. what is the issue?

Comment: Yes I replaced with buttons its amazing once again I thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I have setup a github repo regarding your problem [link](https://github.com/usamaiqbal83/TestingAutoLayouts)

[image]

**Steps:**

1) Top Bar height = 0.17 * superview.width

2) Bottom Bar height = Top Bar height

3) MidSection covers all area between top slab and bottom slab

4) Row1 height = MidSection height * 0.33

5) Cell1 width = Row1 width * 0.5

These are the major constraints, hope it helps

Comment: @jkannan if you want buttons, replace Blob(UIView) with UIButton

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

1. Fix the height of the Top View(In your case the green view). Give the Leading, Trailing and Top constraints to the Superview as 0.
2. Fix the height of the Bottom View(gray one). Give the Leading, Trailing and Bottom constraints as 0.
3. Now place a view in the middle of the top and bottom view. Give Leading, Trailing, Bottom and Top constraints as 0.
4. Place button1 in the middle view. Give the Leading and Top constraints 0 and width proportional to middle view in such a way that the button should be half of the middle view.
5. Give the height of button1 proportional to middle view with the multiplier 0.3. (Change the multiplier value if needed)
6. Make a duplicate button of button1. Give the height and width equal to button1. But the Trailing space to middle view as 0. And Top constraint too.
7. Do the same thing for the remaining four buttons, but give Leading space or Trailing space as per the requirement.

Here the important thing is the height of the button1. You need to check for each value in all the devices. Or else you can simple use a scrollview and fix the content height of it.

Check out the image if needed.

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This guide should help you.
[Autolayout guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1%20Autolayout%20guide)